# How to create a global function and pass variables to it in VBA Access?

Tags: vba, function, ms-access, global-variables, global

In my program I am trying to cut down on repetitive code by putting it into global functions.

In my current setup I am calling the function like:

```
Call [Global variable].Close
```

(global variable is the name of the class module).

This function is looks like;

```
 Public Function Close()
  DoCmd.Close
  Cancel = True
End Function
```

Unfortunately this wont compile properly. What am I doing wrong?? (As an aside I also want to pass variables to and from this function and want to know how this would be done).

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What compile error do you receive?

Comment: A compile error - expected identifier

Comment: That will be because `Close` will be a reserved word.  Try using `Public Function CloseIt()` (or some other name).  But make sure you call the `CloseIt` of an **instance** of the class (as per ThunderFrame's answer).

Comment: Based on some comments you have in ThunderFrame's answer, I think you need to provide more information.  (1) What does your class do?  (2) How is that associated with the form that the user is on?  (3) What part of your code is trying to invoke the class' `Close` function?  (I get the feeling from a comment that you are trying to close the class when the user tries to close a form.)  (4) Is the `Close` function actually in a class, or just in a standard code module?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using a class module, you need an *instance* of that module before you can call its members. That requires either creating the class module as pre-declared (which involves exporting the code, editing in Notepad, and re-importing), or creating an instance with the `New` keyword:

```
Dim myClassInstance As MyClass
Set myClassInstance = New MyClass
myClassInstance.Close
```

But, depending on your use-case, you might better off with the function being available in a standard module - then you can just call it from anywhere, including from within a query.

Comment: It depends. Where are you calling the code from, and what do you want the code to do?

Comment: I want to call the code everytime the user clicks the close button, regardless of what form they are on